# What is the easiest way to create a file server using node/express/postgresql and heroku

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express, heroku

What is the easiest way to create a file server using node/express/postgresql and heroku such that the files will be easily and quickly searchable? For the sake of this experiment assume that the number of files hosted is sufficiently large. In addition it is not as important but if there is a way anyone knows of to store the files in such a way as to mimic a folder/file structure your input would be greatly appreciated!